# Use grep in a GNU make if-statement

Tags: linux, makefile, grep, gnu-make

First: I'm pretty new to linux and I'm already sorry for asking a probably dumb question.
I have a makefile that compiles a latex text into a pdf. That creates a logfile and I have to search for a string in that log file and compile again if the string is in the log-file.
So everything works fine until to the point of my if-statement.
I'm trying to check for the sub-string with the grep command but dont get it to work.
In my solution the if statement is executed even if the substring is not in my logfile.

```
GREP_FINDINGS := $(shell grep 'undefhrined' linux-20.log)

all: clean linux-20.pdf
ifeq ($(GREP_FINDINGS),)
    pdflatex linux-20
endif

linux-20.pdf:
    pdflatex linux-20
    bibtex linux-20
    pdflatex linux-20
    
.PHONY: clean
    
clean:
    echo Cleaning .aux .bbl .blg .log files
    -rm -f *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.log *.pdf
    echo Cleaning complete.
```

Comment: Your makefile states, that to make `all` it should also make `clean` and `linux-20.pdf` (take note that the order in which those two targets will be called is undefined), and one of `linux-20.pdf` target commands is to call `pdflatex linux-20` which is the same as in your `ifeq` statement. Also note, that your statement will NOT be run when the `undefhined` (typo intended?) word is found in the log file.

Comment: @nsilent22 Hey, so i dont really underastand what you mean. It is intended that the pdflatex command is called in my linux-20.pdf AND in the if statement. The importánt thin is, that the second pdflatex command is only called when the sub-string is available in my log-file. The problem is, that I cant find a solution where id does that beghavior. Either it executes always or never even if the sub-string is available. Also the typo in is intended, i was trying if the if statement is executed even with a word that does not exist

Comment: Your if statement will run only when the output of the grep command is empty, that means when the statement is not in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts of this question make me uneasy (such as something being *undefined* after the first pass but all square after the second -- or third?), but if what you're asking for is actually what you want, then I'd put the conditional inside the rule:

```
linux-20.pdf:
    pdflatex linux-20
    bibtex linux-20
    pdflatex linux-20
    !(grep undefined linux-20.log) || pdflatex linux-20
```

Comment: @beta: I'd change `!( command ) ||` -> `command &&`

Comment: @nsilent22 Have you tried it? What if `linux-20.pdf` were *not* the last target you wanted to build? What if the `all` recipe did something?

Comment: @Beta: I'm a bit lost what are you now asking about. In my comment I proposed changing negation and OR list operator to AND list operator.

Comment: @nsilent22: Yes, and if we write the command your way, and "undefined" isn't in the log file, Make will abort and return an error code, which could be very troublesome.

Comment: As one more pass is not always enough with LaTeX, using a while loop would be even better: `while grep undefined linux-20.log; do pdflatex linux-20; done`.